# UglifierJS only showing one copyright comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, uglifyjs

I'm making a rails (3.2.11) app. When I compile my assets I'm only seeing one copyright statement, even though I'm using multiple JS and CSS files that have copyright statements at the top.

I'm guessing that this is because rails is just concatenating all of the js files and then just keeping the copyright statement that is at the top.

I want to make sure to give everyone their due credit. I could manually just add a new file of copyright statements, but is there a way to fix this with the asset pipeline?